# Redirect for iPad, iPhone and Android

Tags: android, iphone, html, ipad, redirect

I have a webpage not rendering properly on mobile and Apple devices, and I have made an alternate version for them. How can I, preferably with html only, make those devices load the alternate version when accessing the main one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to the logic side of the site (php/javascript), you can implement a check to see if the User Agent string the browser sends in their request, contains "iPhone", "iPad", or "Android". Next you can redirect to this other page by using the "Location" response header. For example:

JavaScript:

```
if( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) ) { 
    window.location = "http://address.to.your.mobile.site/";
}
```

PHP:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPhone') !== false) {
    header('Location: http://address.to.your.mobile.site/');
}
```

I'd prefer the PHP solution:
the browser sends a request to the webserver. The webserver will see the user agent is a mobile device and redirect to the correct page. 
As where the JavaScript solution will request the webpage, receive it, load the JavaScript and send a new request to the webserver. (I believe it happens like this, please correct me if I'm wrong)

Plus, as you have mentioned in the comments, not every user has their JavaScript enabled in their browser.

Comment: Although this cuold possibly work, I am afraid that users with disabled javascript might be a problem. Hence the desire to do it in plain html, like using link tags

Comment: I have elaborated my answer with a possible PHP solution. I think it is not possible to achieve the desired effect by using only HTML.

Comment: I just implemented it with some changes and works perfectly. Thanks!